# PHP readfile complete URL

Tags: java, php, python, html

Just a thought as i'm not well informed in .php

But would if be possible to do something like....

```
 readfile("http://pastebin.com/raw/Z646464z"); # $$EncKey=1234$$
 exit; 
}

else

--But to be able Read/Load the url/file alltogether
http://pastebin.com/raw/Z646464z$$EncKey=1234$$
```

---

I know i can put the complete link, but i want something just like that

-$$EncKey=1234$$ is the key/code which the program uses to decrypt the content i just do not want to show it on the URL.

Thank you.

Comment: Users of a PHP-based web page can't see the source code, so they won't see the key.

Comment: They can sniff it out with Fiddler. i've tried.

Comment: I don't see how. `readfile` is communicating between the two servers, the client is not in the loop at all.

Comment: The only way the end user could sniff it would be if you used AJAX in the browser instead of `readfile` in the server.

Comment: Here complete code http://pastebin.com/raw/8iy3Q8Ma ,please help how i can improve...

Comment: You have to put the key into the URL argument to `readfile`. I don't think there's any alternative.

Comment: Yea afraid so, only option. Thank's for checking man, appreciate it!